# How to stop evaluation of a large repl result causing slime with swank clojure to slow down?

Tags: emacs, clojure, io, read-eval-print-loop

Whenever I evaluate a large value that prints a large datastructure into the repl, slime becomes very slow from then on. Typing anything subsequently into the repl shows a delay in values appearing in the repl and further evaluation of any clojure code is slow. The only thing that seems to work is restarting the repl which doesn't seem like a solution.

An simple example of a large datastructure is slurping a file and then printing it (this could even be a fairly small file).

This seems to happen both in Win7 and Ubuntu.

Any ideas on how to stop this and why it is happening would be appreciated!

Comment: Interesting - I observed the same behavior using ClojureBlox on Windows and also was tapping my toes wishing for a way to interrupt while it was executing. Here is code to reproduce: https://gist.github.com/1454300 - processes the screenplay for Pulp Fiction.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When I've run into this issue (which happens often), I simply clear the repl buffer. You can do this with C-c M-o, or by using "Clear Buffer" under the "REPL" menu item. This doesn't restart the repl, and command history and the like are unaffected.

Comment: The reason it works is that this is not a repl issue, but an issue with the size of the buffer in Emacs. Emacs is not good at dealing with overly large buffers.

Comment: After you mentioned this I checked it out, your right, a less history clearing technique is C-c C-o which just flushes the last entry... I'll leave the question open for a bit longer to see if anyone actually has a good reason for this or a fix. I can't imagine that "Emacs can't handle lots of text" is a good excuse for a text editor...

Comment: Emacs can handle very large files, but the repl buffer isn't backed by a file, so techniques such as memmap won't work. Anyway, consider adding "emacs" tag to this question then.

Comment: so your suggesting that I the repl be saved? So that it will be backed as a file?

Comment: @toofarsideways No, I'm just pointing out that the emacs can handle the predominant case of "lots of text", which is editing large files.

Comment: @toofarsideways i should have elaborated slightly, but I typed out my comment in a hurry. ivant is right, it's not about large files, it's about large buffers that are not backed by files.

Answer (score 3):

One way you can control how much info is printed from the REPL is from clojure itself using the [`*print-length*`](http://clojure.github.com/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/%2aprint-length%2a) and [`*print-level*`](http://clojure.github.com/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/%2aprint-level%2a) variables.